# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE half working

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, on-duplicate-key

I have a shopping cart as a DB table called `cart` that stores records of items in each SaaS instances shopping cart. What I want to do, is that if a product is added to the cart for the a user and an identical record already exists, is to update the quantity column in the table to equal the old value plus the new value, only if status = 0, else, enter a new record.

Breakdown:

If the item is already in the cart, update the quantity column to set the new quantity value ONLY if status column = 0, else, add the item to the cart table as a new row.

## Here's what I have so far:

```
    $itemList = $db->query("INSERT INTO 

                                        cart(
                                        `lmsid`, 
                                        `userid`, 
                                        `courseid`, 
                                        `assigned_by`, 
                                        `assigned_on`, 
                                        `quantity`) 

                            VALUES(

                                        :lmsid, 
                                        :userid, 
                                        :courseid, 
                                        :assigned_by, 
                                        :assigned_on, 
                                        1) 

                            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 

                                        `quantity` = `quantity` + values('quantity')
                            )", 

                            array(
                            "lmsid"=>$core['id'], 
                            "userid"=>$user,
                            "courseid"=>$_POST['courseid'], 
                            "assigned_by"=>$userInfo['id'], 
                            "assigned_on"=>time())
    );
```

## At the moment...

1. If a record doesn't exist at all, it's inserted perfectly.
2. If a record exists where status = 0, the existing quantity is updated perfectly.
3. If a record exists where status = 2, the query fails with:

`Unhandled Exception. SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '66-2' for key 'useridAndCourseid'`

The key `useridAndCourseid` in the table is:

```
UNIQUE KEY `useridAndCourseid` (`userid`,`courseid`)
```

The status column is updated to '1' when a product is deleted from a cart, this record stays there forever for our records. The status is updated to '2' when a product has been paid for, again, for our records. When a record is just sitting in the cart waiting to be dealt with, it has a status of 0.

## What I need help with

At the moment the query is half working, but I just don't know how to say '**if record exists and status = 0 update quantity, else, insert new record**'. That's literally all I'm looking to achieve but I think I'm try to over complicate it or I've spent so long trying to overcomplicate it I'm forgotten what I'm after! I'm sure there is a simple solution. If only I could use ON DUPLICATE KEY and a WHERE clause...

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to approach this.  But, if you want a single statement for the `insert`, you need to create a unique index that does what you want.  This index should have a column that takes on some value (say `0`) when `status = 0` and `NULL` at other times.  A `NULL` value is not treated as a duplicated key.  You might call this the `IsActiveFlag`.

If you have such a column, then the index:

```
create index idx_cart(userid, courseid, IsActiveFlag)
```

should allow you to do what you want.